# BeautifulSoup filtering data from list elements on html pages

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to gather data from multiple html pages, specifically the data in the list elements. Im attempting to add this data to a dictionary for later use, ive got to extracting the data as I would expect but my entering the data into a dict is not working as expected. I am currently overwriting each entry rather than adding new entries. Could anyone point out where im going wrong please?

**Current Code**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

person_dict = {}

.....
<snip>
<snip>
.....

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text)

    div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'object-a'})
    ul = div.find('ul', {'id': 'object-a-1'})
    li_a = ul.findAll('a', {'class': 'title'})
    li_p = ul.findAll('p', {'class': 'url word'})
    li_po = ul.findAll('p')

    for a in li_a:
        nametemp = a.text
        name = (nametemp.split(' - ')[0])
        person_dict.update({'Name': name})     #I attempted updating
    for lip in li_p:
        person_dict['url'] = lip.text          #I attempted adding directly

    for email in li_po:   
        reg_emails = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9.]*' + '@')        
        person_dict['email'] = reg_emails.findall(email.text)

print person_dict # results in 1 entry being returned
```

**Test Data**

```
<div id="object-a">
    <ul id="object-a-1">
            <li>
              <a href="www.url.com/person" class="title">Person1</a>
              <p class="url word">www.url.com/Person1</p>
              <p>Person 1, some foobar possibly an email@address.com &nbsp;...</p>
            </li>


            <li>
              <a href="www.url.com/person" class="title">Person2</a>
              <p class="url word">www.url.com/Person1</p>
              <p>Person 2, some foobar possibly an email@address.com &nbsp;...</p>
            </li>


            <li>
              <a href="www.url.com/person" class="title">Person3</a>
              <p class="url word">www.url.com/Person1</p>
              <p>Person 3, some foobar, possibly an email@address.com &nbsp;...</p>
            </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: You're using the `'Name'` key for every iteration aren't you? Keys need to be unique.

Comment: yes I want to add a new `Name` and relevant data each iteration

Comment: Why do you need a dict, just append tuples to a list, like `List.append((name, email, foo))`

Comment: I was under the impression that it would be more convenient in the form of a dictionary. but I am of course quite new to coding, could you explain why it would be better to have a list of tuples please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you need to use a dictionary is up to you, but if you do choose to use one, it would probably be better to have a separate dictionary per list item rather than a single one for all entries.

I would suggest you store all of the entries in a list. The following code shows two suggestions, either use a `tuple` to store the various bits of information per item, or use a dictionary.

If you just intend to display the information or write it to a file, the `tuple` solution would be faster.

```
# Two possible ways of storing your data: a list of tuples, or a list of dictionaries
entries_tuples = []             
entries_dictionary = []

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)

div = soup.find('div', {'id': 'object-a'})
ul = div.find('ul', {'id': 'object-a-1'})

for li in ul.findAll('li'):
    title = li.find('a', {'class': 'title'})
    url_href = title.get('href')
    person = title.text
    url_word = li.find('p', {'class': 'url word'}).text
    emails = re.findall(r'\s+(\S+@\S+)(?:\s+|\Z)', li.findAll('p')[1].text, re.M)       # allow for multiple emails

    entries_tuples.append((url_href, person, url_word, emails))
    entries_dictionary.append({'url_href' : url_href, 'person' : person, 'url_word' : url_word, 'emails' : emails})

for url_href, person, url_word, emails in entries_tuples:
    print '{:25} {:10} {:25} {}'.format(url_href, person, url_word, emails)

print

for entry in entries_dictionary:
    print '{:25} {:10} {:25} {}'.format(entry['url_href'], entry['person'], entry['url_word'], entry['emails'])
```

For your sample HTML, the following would be displayed:

```
www.url.com/person        Person1    www.url.com/Person1       [u'email@address.com']
www.url.com/person        Person2    www.url.com/Person1       [u'email@address.com']
www.url.com/person        Person3    www.url.com/Person1       [u'email@address.com', u'email@address.com']

www.url.com/person        Person1    www.url.com/Person1       [u'email@address.com']
www.url.com/person        Person2    www.url.com/Person1       [u'email@address.com']
www.url.com/person        Person3    www.url.com/Person1       [u'email@address.com', u'email@address.com']
```

Note, extracting email addresses from text is a complete question in itself. The above solution could easily match entries that are not actually well formed email addresses but will suffice for here.

Comment: ok I can see my approach was a little off, thanks for pointing that out, and thank you for answering the question I actually asked. I can see why my dictionary was not updating as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You may be going at it the wrong way.  Try something like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = open('soup.html') # You are opening the file differently
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
list_items = soup.findAll('li')

people = []

for item in list_items:
    name = item.find('a', {'class': 'title'}).text
    url = item.find('p', {'class': 'url word'}).text
    email_text = item.findAll('p')[1].text
    match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', email_text)
    email = match.group(0)

    person = {'name': name, 'url': url, 'email': email}
    people.append(person)

print people
```

Comment: thank you for trying to answer the question I actually asked, I like your approach by adding one entry into the container (list in this case) however could you please explain why you are adding a what looks to be a dictionary into a list? Is there any particular reason you decided on that approach?

Comment: I don't know how you would want to use the data after you collect it but in this way you could iterate the list and get the data in a dictionary containing grouped key, value pairs.